# Computing the address of an object from the address of one of its member subobject

Tags: c++, c++11, offset, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

I am in the following situation:

```
//This is Public
class B{/*usefull stuff*/};
B*f();
void g(B*b)();

//Those classes are only declared the translation unit of f and g.
class Whatever1{/*Implementation details only useful to f and g*/};
class Whatever2{/*Implementation details only useful to f and g*/};
class A{
public:
    Whatever1 w1;
    Whatever2 w2;
    B b;
};
```

In function g, I want to convert the parameter (a pointer to B) to a pointer to A.

**B instances are always wrapped in A instances.**

I ended up with this:

```
ptrdiff_t lag(){
    A a;
    return (char*)&a.b-(char*)&a;}

void g(B*b){
    A*a=(A*)((char*)b-lag());
    //Work with a
}
```

This solution makes me very unconfortable.

**Is it 100% correct and portable to do offset computations like this ?**

**Does it triggers Undefined Behavior in any way ?**

Edit: std::is_standard_layout< A >::value is 1.

Comment: I don't know if it will ever work (it screems "undefined behavior" at me), but you might want to check [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof).

Comment: Also, this question have a smell of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). That is, you show us a solution, but don't tell us the problem that solution tries to solve.

Comment: If you have to ask if something is UB, it probably is (and if you don't have to ask, then it probably is anyway)

Comment: Yes, `offsetof` is the way to go. It will be valid in exactly those situations where your original code is also valid, but with GCC's implementation of `offsetof` (and probably some others too) you get a compile-time diagnostic if using it with types for which it is invalid.

Comment: @hvd About `offsetof` 18.2/4 says that "*If type is not a standard-layout class (Clause 9), the results are undefined*". Unfortunately, the OP doesn't give enough information to deduce if `A` is standard layout or not.

Comment: btw pointer arithmetic is only defined within arrays, so. If `offsetof` is UB then doing it manually is not any less UB.

Comment: @hvd After the edit, my concern about the layout of `A` vanishes. So, I agree with you that `offsetof` is the way to go.

Comment: @CassioNeri About 18.2/4, yes, that's what I meant by "types for which it is invalid". If it's invalid (it turns out it's valid), using `offsetof` could have immediately let the OP know it's invalid.

Comment: @hvd I was just precising what "invalid" means in this case, that is, non standard layout.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I'm not sure about the undefined behavior.  When he does the subtraction, he's doing it on `char*`; pointers into the underlying byte array in which the object resides.  This is an essential feature of C++ if it is to be used for low level code, particularly in the implementation of memory management systems themselves.  (I do think it is probably being abused here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `B` is always contained within an `A`, then it might be much cleaner to add a back reference to B's parent inside A. If that is impractical for whatever reason, then `offsetof` will clean it up a little, but otherwise the approach is valid, if somewhat c-ish.

```
void g(B*b){
    A* a = (A*)(((char*)b)-offsetof(class A,b));
    //Work with a
}
```

Comment: I don't want to add a back reference because I want those objects to be as small as possible I am caching a lot of them.

Comment: We don't know if `A` is standard layout or not (the OP fails to provide this relevant information) and thus `offsetof(class A, b)` might yield UB. Indeed 18.2/4 says that "*If type is not a standard-layout class (Clause 9), the results are undefined*".

Comment: The OP has been edited to include the information `std::is_standard_layout< A >::value == 1`. Hence my previous concern vanishes.

Comment: I would make that cast an explicit `reinterpret_cast` both ways.  And throw in a `static_assert` about standard layout, another in the constructor of `A`, and maybe have `B` be constructed by a type that is private to `A` so the only way to construct `B` is being an `A`.  There are probably ways for UB to sneak in still, but unlikely to occur in practice.