# Calculating this pointer of containing object

Tags: c++, inner-classes, pointer-arithmetic

Is the following portable and standard-conforming C++, always returning "success"?

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

struct Containing {
    struct {
        Containing * get_containing () {
            return reinterpret_cast<Containing *> (
                (char *) this - offsetof (Containing, inner)
            );
        }
    } inner;
};


int main () {
    Containing c;
    std::cout
        << (c.inner.get_containing () == &c ? "success" : "fail")
        << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I deleted the possibly duplicate question. My only question is: "Is this standard-conforming or not?" Btw, the "duplicate question" votes start to make Stackoverflow useless, as people voting for closing do not seem to read what has been asked.

Comment: I did read what had been asked ;)  That said, I've now retracted the close-vote, as the edit means there's no real overlap any more...

Comment: BTW, here is a slightly more complex example which fails: http://ideone.com/2sr2JF.  You will need add some casts to `char *` to make this work more generally (UB notwithstanding).

Comment: Thank you. Seems to be sufficient to cast `this`.

Comment: What do you mean calculating "this pointer"? Are you trying to get the VTable? For that you can just do:  `DWORD* VTable = *reinterpret_cast<DWORD**>(&SomeInstance);`.. Then again, I'm not sure this is what you want..

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: It seems pretty clear that he wants `this`, but for the containing instance.

Comment: Then what is the point of the offsetof? Why not just return "this"? Why do that as well when he can just do `&instance`?

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: Because that would be `this` for the **inner** class.

Comment: Quoth the standard: "The mapping performed by reinterpret_cast<> is implementation defined".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth http://ideone.com/csqQ1F <--- That's what I mean. OP is going through quite a lot to calculate the "this pointer" when it's already there.. I guess he would need it if the class itself wants the address but it doesn't really make much sense or seem to have much use.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: That seems to be the same as the OP's code, but without the cast.

Comment: You're right. Didn't notice that `&c.inner` is the same as `&c` which is the same as `c.inner.get_containing()` which is the same as `this`. In this case, what is the point of `get_containing()`? OP can return `this` from `get_containing()`.  http://ideone.com/UjJpZY

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: Yup, I guess this is a degenerate case because `offsetof(inner) == 0`.  I imagine the OP wants the more general case where `&outer != &inner`.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395008/computing-the-address-of-an-object-from-the-address-of-one-of-its-member-subobje/20395116#20395116

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

struct Containing {
    struct {
        Containing * get_containing () {
            return reinterpret_cast<Containing *> (
                (char *) this - offsetof (Containing, inner)
            );
        }
    } inner;
};


int main () {
    Containing c;
    std::cout
        << (c.inner.get_containing () == &c ? "success" : "fail")
        << std::endl;
}
```

The specific code you show, which I’ve repeated above, is OK, because `reinterpret_cast` to/from first element of a POD is supported for C compatibility.

As I recall C++11 extended the set of types where that `reinterpret_cast` works.

However, as soon as you introduce a virtual function or other non-POD’y stuff you exceed the operating regime of `offsetof`, as well as that guaranteed `reinterpret_cast`.

---

**Standardese**. By using the “find” function in my PDF reader, applied to the document [N3290.pdf] (the final draft of C++11, identical to the standard), in three mouse clicks the following info about `offsetof` was offered:

> C++11 §18.2/4:
>   “The macro `offsetof`(*type*, *member-designator*) accepts a restricted set of *type* arguments in this International
>   Standard. If *type* is not a standard-layout class (Clause 9), the results are undefined.”

Similarly, by clicking on section heading 9 about “Classes” and then asking the PDF reader to search for `reinterpret_cast`, I found …

> C++11 9.2/20:
>   “A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a `reinterpret_cast`, points to its
>   initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa”

---

**In-practice**. Using `offsetof` for the first member is bit meaningless since it's guaranteed to be at offset 0 (no padding before). In order to make this thing meaningful you have to mean some logical generalization of the given code, where …

- The relevant member is not the first member.
- The pointer arithmetic is done with pointer to byte (e.g. `char`).

Then for POD types, or C++11 more general standard-layout, the `offsetof` is fine, but the `reinterpret_cast` needs specific compiler support. With Visual C++ it’s OK. With g++ you’d better either, if possible, turn off its silly-warnings and associated silly-optimizations, or make a detour through a `void` pointer.

Exeeding the limits of `offsetof` is not in general a good idea. E.g. with virtual inheritance the offsets can vary widely, not deducible from only static type information.